# Do you just call forward declarations and prototype declarations "declarations"?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what the difference is between forward declarations and prototype declarations in C++. Then, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087207) and Angew claims that none of the two terms exist in C++, but they all really just a declarations... But how would you then talk about what otherwise is known as forward declarations without using "forward declaration"? Like if we have this code:

```
class B;
class A{B b;};
class B{A a;}
```

If I just say "The declaration of B that appears before A", nobody can really know that I am talking about a declaration that is supposed to be defined later on.. So how can I be more specific about that using correct C++ terminology?

The same goes for prototype declaration. This term can explain a more specific situation compared to just saying declaration.

Comment: `class B;` is a "declaration whose sole constituent is a _elaborated-type-specifier_" in Standardese. It is also informally known as a forward declaration. But I think this question is largely opinion-based.

Comment: `class B;` is a declaration. `class A{B b;};` is a definition (but definitions are also declarations).

Comment: People who know what a "forward declaration" is will understand you. It works much the same in C++ as in Pascal, even if only one of the languages has a `forward` keyword.

Comment: I understand "forward declaration" but I don't understand "prototype declaration"...

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah, but that does not change the fact that in some cases, you have delimit your vocabulary to respect the the C++ terminology, right... So can you help with that?

Comment: @over - I would use "forward declare" as an informal term for having `class B;` in the `"a.h"` header to avoid having to include `"b.h"`. In this case to avoid a circular include, in the general case to reduce the dependencies between the header files. Very often there is only one class in each header file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c  perhaps this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I would call:

```
class B;
```

A forward declaration in your example.  It informs the compiler that B is a class, which is enough information to refer to B in some ways, without defining B further (at the moment).  This can be used as a way to solve circular references between header files, when you need to refer to a class that refers to the class you are declaring or defining.  (As in your example, but sometimes A and B are in different header files, and you can't include A in the B header and B in the A header, so 'forward declaring' B solves this issue.)

I would call any function declaration where there is not a function body a 'declaration'.  Declaring functions in a header file, and defining them in a cpp file allows header files to only include declarations, which is enough information for consumers of the header file to compile, without the baggage of all of the full function definitions in the header file.  When declarations and definitions are mixed in header files, and the header is included multiple times in a project, duplicate definition errors may occur.

I don't think that 'prototype declaration' is really a term that is used.  I would say that a 'declaration' might also be referred to as a 'function prototype'.  That might be more of an old C term.