# How to Call a Function Without Initializing it Before other one C++

Tags: c++, c++11

My Problem here is that i have initialized a function mainscr() which on a condition call vdetails(). but as the code is shown below the program doesn't compile because of either of the functions is not initialized before the other. If i keep mainscr() on top of vdetails() mainscr will not run but vdetails() will because mainscr() is initialized before. Can anyone suggest me on how i can  declare the function as to be used from anywhere.

Tried using Header file in which already vdetails() is included but getting error like include nested too deep.

```
void mainscr()
{
    stringstream foos (detamt);
    foos >> detamto;
    char flago;
    cout<<"Welcome To Maxon Bank Banking Portal"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"  Please Choose From the Following: "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"  1. View Details "<<endl<<endl; cout<<"  2. Check Balance"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"  3. Deposit Cash "<<endl<<endl; cout<<"  4. Withdraw Cash "<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"  Option: ";
    cin>>flago;
    if (flago=='1')
    {
        vdetails();
    }

void vdetails()
{
   system("cls");
        cout<<"Maxon Bank Banking Portal"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"  "<<detacno<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"  "<<detn<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"  "<<detactype<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"  AVAILABLE BALANCE: INR "<<detamto<<endl<<endl;
        Cont();
        system("cls");
        mainscr();
}
```

Actually i am trying to ask user their input if input is 1 then that will show them their account details and go back to mainscr() where this thing will happen again if input is same.

Comment: Just put `void vdetails();` on the top.

Comment: Put the definitions in a header file and #include it at the top.

Comment: And it's called *defining*.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: Thanks guys the first method worked by making a forward reference.

Comment: Your implementation may cause stack to overflow. Assume flago variable is always '1' then functions mainscr and vdetails gets called recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a forward reference which is basically the signature of the function without body.

```
void mainscr();
void vdetails();
```

Put those above your implemenations (or better in the corresponding header) and your functions know each other

Comment: Actually Ive been developing since a month so dint know it.

Comment: Please note that term "forward reference" is [misleading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) in this context. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087145/difference-between-prototype-declaration-and-forward-declaration